# How to have a button have a ripple as well as a custom shape

Tags: android, android-animation, android-button, android-background

When I try to have the two of them together but they will either override each other or the background becomes transparent.

Button shape:

```
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#048403"/>
<corners
    android:radius="2dp" />

<padding
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="3dp"
    android:bottom="3dp" />
<solid
    android:color="@color/safeGreen" />
```

Button ripple:

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/darkGreen">
    <item android:drawable="@color/safeGreen"/>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this I found this solution that works in case anyone is interested. You create a new resource as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkGreen" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape" />
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#048403"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="2dp" />

        <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="3dp"
            android:bottom="3dp" />
        <solid
            android:color="#1b711b" />
    </shape>
</item>
```